# Azure Data Factory pipeline concurrency issue

Tags: azure, concurrency, pipeline

I set the concurrency for my Azure ADF pipeline to 1 to avoid having two pipelines running simultaneously:

[Concurrency setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvWqG.png)

Nevertheless, the ADF is launching them concurrently:

[Overlapping pipeline runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBBbS.png)

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency has set to one which means one pipeline will start executing and next the other one, based on your screenshot we can see that after the first initiation, second one got started.

We need to understand how these limits apply to your Data Factory pipelines

Refer to [mrpaulandrew](https://mrpaulandrew.com/2020/12/02/data-factory-activity-concurrency-limits-what-happens-next/) blog for better understanding on concurrency limits.

If your pipeline has a concurrency policy, verify that there are no old pipeline runs in progress.

Comment: Good answer. Make sure no old pipelines running is important when test concurrency. 
I created a `concurrency==1` pipeline with a `wait(10min)` activity, multiply pipeline runs will queue when manually triggered. And I noticed that a pipeline is marked as **started** the time being pushed in queue.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots it looks like you manually triggered the runs. In that case you are physically overwriting the purpose of concurrency. It works best on Scheduled pipelines to only allow 1 instance to be triggered by Data Factory at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency setting don't apply to manual triggers